# how to build flyway from git source repo?

Tags: flyway

would like to build flyway 4.0 from git source code (https://github.com/flyway/flyway).  Im new to this java development. Could someone help me to get the steps ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with compiling flyway from source.  One is that there's a [problem with using maven 3.3](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/996)---it gives you an error telling you that it's missing S3 keys.  Until it's fixed, you need to downgrade to [maven 3.2.5](http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.5/).  Secondly, the proprietary drivers are not available in maven, meaning that the default `maven install` won't work.

If you don't need the proprietary jars, you can use this command, which I found in [.travis.yml](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/.travis.yml#L9) minus the `-B` batch flag:

```
$ mvn install -P-CommercialDBTest -P-CommandlinePlatformAssemblies -DskipTests=true
```

This will compile all the jars into your local `~/.m2/repository/org/flywaydb` directory.

You could also [install the proprietary jars](http://flywaydb.org/contribute/code/database.html), but I don't think that's necessary unless you are developing against them.  I haven't tried that.

Comment: I'm using maven 3.3.9 and I still get an error involving s3 and it specifically fails on building `flyway-commandline` (while succeeding on all previous targets): `mvn install -P-InstallableDBTest -P-CommercialDBTest -P-CommandlinePlatformAssemblies -DskipTests=true`.

Answer (score -2):

If your application does not run on the JVM, you could simply [install the command-line tool](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/) from their web site (they have builds for Windows, Linux and OS X).

If you want to [integrate flyway to your JVM-based application](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/), add the `org.flywaydb:flyway-core:3.2.1` dependency to your project, using whatever build tool you rely on (Maven, Gradle, Leiningen). You may also want to add one of the JDBC drivers to your project's dependencies. Then build as you usually would.

A third way is to [install a plugin](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/) (for either Maven or Gradle, depending on what you use).

Comment: It shows some dependency issues.. Do we need aws to build this ? Pls help

Comment: You do not need to clone the rep and build flyway from source. Just use add the jar dependency to your project. See the updated answer.